# Are Capital-sigma summation notation and Einstein summation notation the same thing? If not, what is the difference?

Tags: notation

There are two Wikipedia pages describing summation notation: [Capital-sigma summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) and [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Are these two notations the same? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Einstein notation forgoes the $\Sigma$

Answer (score 0):

As the Wikipedia entry explains, Einstein notation is a short-form way of expressing sums. In Einstein notation, contrary to Sigma notation, we omit the summation symbol $\Sigma$.

$$
\underset{\text{Sigma notation}}{\sum _{i=1}^{3}c_{i}x^{i}} \longrightarrow \underset{\text{Einstein notation}}{c_{i}x^{i}}
$$